# React native IOS not loading incoming html for OAUTH login

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, web, openid

I have a recent problem with our react-native related to ios. We are using react-native-app-auth for custom OpenId, Oauth login in our app. In basic terms package sends authorise request to our endpoints and then receives html code for login page to render it in web browser. Previously it was working completely fine but after ios 16.4 something is introduced that basically blocks this OpenId login page to render correctly. Will attach photos so that you can understand what I mean.
And also just letting you know both react-native and the react-native-app-auth versions are latest.[Before ios 16.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM5WR.png)[After ios 16.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyzgS.jpg)

I basically tried downgrading react-native it didn’t worked and trying to basically identify the issue but can’t succedded so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might want to connecting your device to your Mac and using the safari developer mode to debug the web view in your app

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, I tried doing that and funny thing is safari developer mode works in IOS versions before 16.4 and not in 16.4 itself

Comment: It looks like they may have prevented debugging ASWebAuthentication sessions in 16.4.  Can you load your auth web page in a normal Safari browser window?  It looks like a CSS problem or similar

Comment: @Paulw11 the problem is, I can't load it in normal safari browser because its OpenID auth0 authentication thing which implemented using react-native-app-auth, and dont understand why it doesn’t work on ios16.4 but works on 16.1